# What is side-by-side installation meant(one of the .NET Core primary characteristics)

Tags: .net-core, .net-5

In .Net Core documentation mentioned many characteristics for it. One of them is side-by-side installation. What is that mean and what is the benefits?

Comment: Microsoft no longer ensures that the .NET runtime is present on the user's machine.  They don't want that job anymore, it is not a pleasant one, either you or your user has to take care of that now.  Necessarily that requires that each program can have its own copy of the runtime to avoid breaking another.  Lots of copies, typically, modern disk storage is cheap and networks fast.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple versions of .NET Core. Example 3.1, 2.2, and 1.0 all running at the same time. This wasn't possible in .NET Framework.

Comment: It was, actually.   .NET 1.0, 1.1, 2.0-3.5, 4.x are side-by-side.

Comment: @HansPassant Nice catch. I forgot about the major versions